# Groups in Carbon Fields Plugin

Tags: wordpress, carbon-fields

is there any possibility to make group in Carbon Fields, which will be saved as Serialized data in Database (whole group in one database row)?

Something like Group field in Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the solution you're looking for is **Complex fields**.
Please take a look at the documentation:
https://docs.carbonfields.net/#/fields/complex

Comment: Complex fields isn't exactly that what I am looking for. I am looking for "Complex fields" without repeating function. Group of fields, which I can call using array, but can't be repeated.

May I have another question: Carbon fields plugin saves all data as: one field per database row. Can't many rows have bad influence on website performance?